# How to create directory with write permissions for admin only

Tags: c#

How to create directory with write permissions for admin only in C#?

I saw I can use something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\my\directory");
DirectorySecurity security = directory.GetAccessControl();

security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"MYDOMAIN\JohnDoe", 
                        FileSystemRights.Modify, 
                        AccessControlType.Allow));

directory.SetAccessControl(security);
```

**But how can I remove the write access from all other users?**
*I need to do it dynamically, I don't know who the other users are.*

Thank You.

Comment: No, because it show how to specify access to the administrator but not how to remove the access from all the other in the PC